# webpack/typescript error "Invalid configuration object ... - configuration.resolve.extensions[0]"

Tags: typescript, webpack

I followed [this tutorial](http://david-barreto.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-webpack/) and then [this tutorial](http://david-barreto.com/configuring-webpack-with-typescript/) as I am trying to use webpack with typescript. Everything was running fine after I finished the first tutorial (webpack w/out typescript).

However once I followed the second tutorial and ran `npm run build` I am getting this error:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.

I have not been able to find a solution to this anywhere.

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.ts',
  output: {
    filename: './bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest versions of webpack don't permit passing empty string to `module.resolve.extensions` array like you are doing, just remove the empty string or replace it with some extension you want to support

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.ts',
  output: {
    filename: './bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts'] // don't specify the empty string, add '.js' if you want to import plain javascript files into typescript 
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [ // should use 'rules' instead of 'loaders', 'loaders' is retained for backward compatability only
      { test: /.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: I just figured this out right before I saw your answer. I'll mark this as right answer once I can. thank you

Comment: Also, `module.loaders` is the legacy field, it should be `module.rules` instead for the latest version

Comment: @krummens I did actually

Comment: Oh sorry. Didn't see that. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know why webpack examples passed in empty strings in the first place?